# OpsHub VSOnline Migration Utility failed: Cannot create configuration - Error occured while fetching metdata for Test Suite

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

**OpsHub-014764:** 
Could not fetch the fields metadata for destination, underlying cause : 
    OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getFiledCollection. 
    Server Error : **Error occured while fetching metdata for Test Suite**

I've been migration various projects the last couple of days. The one project is giving me the below error during the Migration Configuration creation process with the very last step to "Finish":

```
2015-03-16 14:07:06,958 [1] ERROR com.opshub.eai.mapper.server.OIMMapperException: OpsHub-014764: Could not fetch the fields metadata for destination, underlying cause : OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getFiledCollection. Server Error : Error occured while fetching metdata for Test Suite:   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementWebService4.QueryTestPlans(ResultsStoreQuery query)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestPlanHelper.Query(String queryText)
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSTestSuiteClient.getFieldCollection(String entityName, String projectName) in f:\Ashish Docs\Checkouts\OVSMU Branch\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSTestSuiteUtility.cs:line 631 caused by : Team project Dash not found.
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: com.opshub.eai.mapper.server.OIMMapperException: OpsHub-014764: Could not fetch the fields metadata for destination, underlying cause : OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed getFiledCollection. Server Error : Error occured while fetching metdata for Test Suite:   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementWebService4.QueryTestPlans(ResultsStoreQuery query)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestPlanHelper.Query(String queryText)
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSTestSuiteClient.getFieldCollection(String entityName, String projectName) in f:\Ashish Docs\Checkouts\OVSMU Branch\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSTestSuiteUtility.cs:line 631 caused by : Team project Dash not found.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at TFSMigrationUI.ViewModel.MigrationSummeryViewModel.createConfigWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in e:\OVSMUBranch\TFSMigrationUI\ViewModel\MigrationSummeryViewModel.cs:line 635
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

I don't have a clue where to even begin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error isn't quite detailed enough to see where the issue lies. It seemed to be something with test-related work items.

Turns out something had gone wrong with the creation of the Visual Studio Team Services Team Project (but it didn't report and errors though).

**After deleting the VS Team Services project, and re-creating a blank project the above issue was resolved.**

Hope this helps someone.